# Find all n for which $2^n$ divides $3^n-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all positive integers such that $2^n$ divides $3^n-1$.

I tried factoring $3^n-1$ as such:
$$3^n-1=(3-1)(3^{n-1}+3^{n-2}+3^{n-3}+\cdots+3+1).$$
But now I'm stuck.

Comment: $n=1,2$ are probably the only ones.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Look up "lifting the exponent" lemma.